# Inaccessible due to its protection level Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the code that's creating the error:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.ImageEffects;

public class GS_GlobalFog : GS_SliderBase {

protected override void GraphicsPresetLow() {
    SetFog(false);
}

protected override void GraphicsPresetMedium() {
    SetFog(true);
}

protected override void GraphicsPresetHigh() {
    SetFog(true);
}

protected override void GraphicsPresetUltra() {
    SetFog(true);
}

protected override void OnSliderValueChange() {
    SetFog(System.Convert.ToBoolean(Value));
}

void SetFog(bool value) {
    cam.GetComponent<GlobalFog>().enabled = value;

    slider.value = System.Convert.ToInt16(value);
  }
}
```

This is the error that Visual Studio 2015 is giving me:

> CS0122 'GlobalFog' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: Could you publish `GlobalFog` class declaration ?

Comment: Did you mean `cam.GetComponent<GS_GlobalFog>()...`

Comment: @OrelEraki Well, I copied this from my main menu from an old scene and it worked perfectly fine there. It's this scene that gives the error: "No MonoBehaviour scripts in the file, or their names do not match the file name." whilst the filename is GS_GlobalFog

Comment: basically you want "public" rather than "protected" or "private".  it's difficult to believe you really need to use "protected override" for any reason, if you're just getting started with c#